# Need to make a continuous led glow

Tags: led

I want to make a LED circuit with the following specifications

1. The LED shall glow when given voltage (by using push switch)
2. The LED should glow even after releasing Push switch till the power supply is reset.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what have you found by searching this site or the rest of the Internet? Without such information, your question shows no effort on your part, and becomes a candidate for being closed.

Comment: insufficient preliminary research

Answer (score 3):

- SW1 is the push switch you refer to in your question
- SW2 to 'reset' the power supply

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feG3l1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Once the [SCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon-controlled_rectifier) is [triggered](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/thyristor-circuit.html) it will stay in conducting state until the current through A-K will be interrupted.

At the time of writing your question, there are no details available about voltage and current ratings, so sizing of the components is left out of this answer.